# Abp framework:: How to show/ hide menus based on features

Tags: abp

I'm in the playground learning lots of things about the new [abp framework](https://github.com/abpframework). Congrats to all people involved here, really good initiative!.

I have a question about how to apply features to menus in the application.

I have created a new feature using a FeatureDefinitionProvider abstract class and I can enable or disable in the host or tenant configuration at runtime. Cool!!

I have created a new menu implementing IMenuContributor interface and I can see my new menu at runtime. Cool!!

Now, and maybe I'm wrong. I would like to apply the RequiredFeature DataNotation to show/ hide the menu based on the feature. Like this:

```
[RequiresFeature("SalesModule")]
public class SalesMenuContributor : IMenuContributor
{
//Sales menu contributor
}
```

When I deactivate my feature from the Host/ Tenant, the menu doesn't hide. I don't really know what I'm missing.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [IFeatureChecker Service](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Features#ifeaturechecker-service) to check the feature. You can resolve the `IFeatureChecker` service from the [context.ServiceProvider](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Navigation-Menu#resolving-dependencies) in the menu contributor. In this way, you can conditionally add menu items to the menu.

`[RequiresFeature]` only works in controllers or application services..

Answer (score 2):

Here the code based on the Hilalkan answer:

```
public class SalesMenuContributor : IMenuContributor
{
            var featureChecker = context.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFeatureChecker>();

            if (await featureChecker.IsEnabledAsync("SalesModule"))
            {
               //[add your menu item][1]
            }
}
```